# index of first non-nil value in array

Tags: ruby

What's the best way (in terms of both idiom and efficiency) to find the index of the first non-nil value in an array?

I've come up with `first_non_null_index = array.index(array.dup.compact[0])`...but is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby 1.9 has the `find_index` method:

```
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > [nil, nil, false, 5, 10, 20].find_index { |x| not x.nil? } # detect false values
 => 2 
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > [nil, nil, false, 5, 10, 20].find_index { |x| x }
 => 3
```

`find_index` seems to be available in [backports](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) if needed in Ruby earlier than 1.8.7.

Comment: this will wring if array =[nil, nil, nil,  nil,  nil]

Comment: index is an alias of find_index, so [nil, nil,1].index{|x| x } works too.

Comment: I find [nil, nil, 5, 10].index(&:present?) in Rails is succinct as long as you aren't concerned about false values.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer is in the question only.
Only change

```
first_non_null_index = (array.compact.empty?) "No 'Non null' value exist" :  array.index(array.dup.compact[0]
```

Consider following example

```
array = [nil, nil, nil,  nil,  nil]
first_non_null_index = array.index(array.dup.compact[0]) #this will return '0' which is wrong
```